# .htaccess newb - RewriteRule not matching 2nd rule, why?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently migrating from [isapi_rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) to .htaccess. I'm having some difficulty and I think it's something basic, but I'm not terribly familiar with .htaccess.

I have the two rules like so:

```
RewriteRule ^testing/ /test/index.html?test=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^testing/foo-bar/ /test/index.html?test=2 [NC]
```

Yet the second rule never matches. If I go to http://mydomain.com/testing/foo-bar/ then I will only see the first rule. Why is that? And can it be easily fixed?

I have many rules (outputted from the database to write the .htaccess file )and ordering them in a particular order isn't really possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your mistake is not including the dollar sign.

I'm not certain but I think it should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^testing$ /test/index.html?test=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^testing/foo-bar$ /test/index.html?test=2 [NC]
```

Comment: Very close! I had to leave the trailing slash with the dollar sign. `^/testing/$ /test/index...` Thanks!

Comment: Ah, figured you'd want the slash, dunno why I took it out. Glad it worked!